# Python requests API using proxy for https request get 407 Proxy Authentication Required

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests

I've been struggling with my company proxy to make an https request.

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPProxyAuth

proxy_string = 'http://user:password@url_proxt:port_proxy'

s = requests.Session()
s.proxies = {"http": proxy_string , "https": proxy_string}
s.auth = HTTPProxyAuth(user,password)

r = s.get('http://www.google.com') # OK
print(r.text)
r = s.get('https://www.google.com',proxies={"http": proxy_string , "https": proxy_string}) #OK
print(r.text)
r = s.get('https://www.google.com') # KO
print(r.text)
```

When KO, I have the following exception :

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required',)))
```

I looked online but didn't find someone having this specific issue with HTTPS.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to the amazing help of Lukasa, I solved my issue.

[Please see discussion on fix here](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/2911)
or set :

```
session.trust_env=False
```

Comment: Did not work for me !

Answer (score 1):

I personally solved the above problem on my system by updating the environment variables http_proxy,https_proxy,socks_proxy,ftp_proxy.

First enter the command on your terminal : printenv

This should show you the environment variables on your system.

In my case intially:
http_proxy=http://proxyserver:port/

I changed it to : http_proxy=http://username:password@proxy:port/

using the command 
export http_proxy="http://username:password@proxy:port/"

Similarly for https_proxy,socks_proxy,ftp_proxy

Answer (score 1):

Other way i have resolved is - speak with your corporate IT administrator and find a direct proxy port which connects to external domain (with / without password)

pip install --proxy=http://proxyhost:**proxy_port** pixiedust

Found from other colleagues using the proxy (proxy_port direct connection) in their eclipse settings (network)

Answer (score 0):

To anyone else that tried the accepted answer's "session.trust_env=False" with no success, there may be a deeper issue that produces a similar error (which is probably not the issue the OP had): There may be a corporate proxy configuration that requires specific headers to be sent upon CONNECT, and python requests doesn't send them ('User-Agent' and 'Host', for example).

I do not have a solution for that at the moment. See https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/5028 for a discussion on the subject.