# Python URL Request under corporate proxy

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests, urllib

I'm writing this application where the user can perform a web search to obtain some information from a particular website.
Everything works well except when I'm connected to the Internet via Proxy (it's a corporate proxy).
The thing is, **it works sometimes**.
By sometimes I mean that if it stops working, all I have to do is to use any web browser (Chrome, IE, etc.) to surf the internet and then python's requests start working as before.
The error I get is:
`OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required',)`
My guess is that some sort of credentials are validated and the proxy tunnel is up again.
I tried with the proxies handlers but it remains the same.
My doubts are:

1. How do I know if the proxy need authentication, and if so, how to do it without hardcoding the username and password since this application will be used by others?
2. Is there a way to use the Windows default proxy configuration so it will work like the browsers do?
3. What do you think that happens when I surf the internet and then the python requests start working again?

I tried with `requests` and `urllib.request`

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python requests API using proxy for https request get 407 Proxy Authentication Required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34025964/python-requests-api-using-proxy-for-https-request-get-407-proxy-authentication-r)

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is any proxy setting in chrome

Comment: Yes, there is a proxy setting

Comment: Thanks, but as I said, I've tried with proxies configuration and nothing changed. I also don't want to hardcode the password and if possible avoid asking it. I'm also not sure if that would help since I did a test hardcoding my username and password and nothing changed