# Unable to get through Company Proxy for conda & pip

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

After updating my conda-build version, I have been unable to run the following commands:

```
1. conda install <package>
2. pip install < package>
```

And would get the following error:

> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required',))': /simple/python/

1. I have already set & updated the http & https setting on my environment variable.
2. I also tried this on Anaconda:
   set http_proxy=http://username:password@your_proxy:your_port
   set https_proxy=https://username:password@your_proxy:your_port

Prior to updating the conda-build, everything worked fine behind the company proxy.

I am currently using:
conda version : 4.7.5
conda-build 3.18.7
python version 3.6.5.final.0
user-agent: conda/4.7.5 requests/2.18.4 CPython/3.6.5 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.17763

Comment: Sorry to ask an obvious question, but when setting the proxy settings, you have used your actual user name, password, proxy and proxy port right and not just the values in the above? Also, the top answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34025964/python-requests-api-using-proxy-for-https-request-get-407-proxy-authentication-r) may help.

Comment: Hi, yes, i used my actual username &  password. My proxy setting used to work till i updated the conda-build version.

Answer (score 0):

Proxy Authentication required 407 error means that the site is disallowed by the proxy administrators. Proxy Authentication Required means you need elevated network administrator privileges.