# Why does my python request to http runs, but not to https?

Tags: python, https, python-requests

I need to get a connection to this uri: uri = 'https://www.wfs.nrw.de/geobasis/wfs_nw_inspire-flurstuecke_alkis?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=2.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&STOREDQUERY_ID=urn:ogc:def:query:OGC-WFS::GetFeatureById&ID=CadastralParcel_05518904700963______'

Because it dosen't work, i tryed this to find my misstakes:

```
import requests
import urllib.request

uri = 'http://www.google.de'
uriS = 'https://www.google.de'

myproxies =  urllib.request.getproxies()

try:
    r = requests.get(uri)
    print('HTTP OK')
except:
    print('HTTP NOT OK')
try:
    r = requests.get(uri, proxies = myproxies)
    print('HTTP WITH PROXIES OK')
except:
    print('HTTP WITH PROXIES NOT OK')
try:
    r = requests.get(uriS)
    print('HTTPS OK')
except:
    print('HTTPS NOT OK')
try:
    r = requests.get(uriS, proxies = myproxies)
    print('HTTPS WITH PROXIES OK')
except:
    print('HTTPS WITH PROXIES NOT OK')
```

This is the result:

```
HTTP OK
HTTP WITH PROXIES OK
HTTPS NOT OK
HTTPS WITH PROXIES NOT OK
```

This happens when i do it in the console:

```
>>> import requests
>>> uri = 'https://www.google.de'
>>> r = requests.get(uri)

Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.8\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 594, in urlopen
        self._prepare_proxy(conn)
      File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.8\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 815, in _prepare_proxy
        conn.connect()
      File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.8\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 324, in connect
        self._tunnel()
      File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.8\apps\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 911, in _tunnel
        message.strip()))
    OSError: Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authorization Required

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.8\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 445, in send
        timeout=timeout
      File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.8\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
        _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
      File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.8\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 398, in increment
        raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
    urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.google.de', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authorization Required')))

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.8\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
        exec(code, self.locals)
      File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
      File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
      File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.8\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 72, in get
        return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
      File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.8\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 58, in request
        return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
      File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.8\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 512, in request
        resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
      File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.8\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 622, in send
        r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
      File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.8\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 507, in send
        raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
    requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.google.de', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authorization Required')))
```

Comment: You should print out some details from the exceptions.

Comment: It's hard to answer like that. It could be different reasons. You shouldn't catch the error to see what the stack trace is. My intuition would be that you have a problem with you OpenSSL installation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python requests API using proxy for https request get 407 Proxy Authentication Required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34025964/python-requests-api-using-proxy-for-https-request-get-407-proxy-authentication-r)

Comment: The information was intressting, but we solved the Problem in an other way.

Answer (score 0):

We solved the Problem!

The code was correct.

**We (oure network admin) have put the uri "https://www.wfs.nrw.de" on a list for uri with no authentication needed.**

```
import requests
import urllib.request
myproxies = urllib.request.getproxies()
uri = 'https://www.wfs.nrw.de/geobasis/wfs_nw_inspire-flurstuecke_alkis?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=2.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&STOREDQUERY_ID=urn:ogc:def:query:OGC-WFS::GetFeatureById&ID=CadastralParcel_05518904700963______'
r = requests.get(uri, proxies = myproxies)
print(r.text)
```